# Data Studio Normal distrbution Chart

Tags: looker-studio, normal-distribution

I newbie to google data studio. May I know if data studio got any plugin or build-in to plot a normal distribution chart?
[image]

Comment: Please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817194/generate-normally-distributed-series-using-bigquery) for a workable solution. You can have DS draw a chart from there.

Comment: I think [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661239/histogram-and-distribution-in-google-data-studio) also covers to your needs.

Comment: Also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725054/how-to-make-a-simple-histogram-representing-a-distribution-in-google-data-stud/65893535) was great as it provided a way to auto-generate bins with calculated variable.